# If I am integrating a function $f(y)$ with respect to $x$ but no actual $x$ variable, should I treat that function as a constant?

Tags: integration

I am trying to integrate $\cos(y^2) dx$ from the bound $y^3$ to $y^3$. Since I am integrating with respect to $x$ and not $y$, should I treat the function as a constant and integrate normally?

I tried putting it in online calculators such as symbolab but they keep changing $dx$ in to $dy$.

I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: The integral from $y^{3}$ to $y^{3}$ is $0$.

Comment: You are correct. You treat the term as a constant with respect to $x$. You work more with integrals like this if you take multivariable calculus

Comment: As @KaviRamaMurthy pointed out, it doesn't matter, if the upper & lower bounds are the same then the integral has value zero.